# Input controls are not visible in hypelinked report of JR Server CP 4.7 and 5.0

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am using *JasperReports Server CP 4.7* and imported all the files from *JR Server 4.5* to new server. But I don't see the parameters if I click on any hyper-linked report, in case  if hyperlinked report has any other input controls parameter. I cant see those input controls.

How can I solve this problem?

Is it a bug of *JR Server 4.7*?
I also have same problem with JR server 5.0.

Comment: Having a similar issue.  Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: not yet, so i decided to use JaserReport Server CP 4.5.

Comment: It turned out that my issue had to do with an incorrect database connection.  I had just upgrade to 4.7 and none of the input controls were showing up.  But I noticed that when I tried to open up a report with no input controls it wasn't working either.  So I identified that the database connection string was wrong and that cleared both issues up.  It would have been nice if Jasper gave some kind of error rather than simply not displaying the input controls.

Comment: but my problem is when i hyperlinked any report with graph or any text in report I dont see any input control in hyperlinked report and if I want to change the parameter value in hyperlinked report I have to go back to the main report then i can see the changes in hyperlinked report, but in JasperReport server 4.5 even i can pass all the input control parameter from main report to hyperlinked report. Are you also having the same issue?

Comment: No, my problem was just the database connection.  That and a lack of an error message from Jasper.

Comment: @Tom: Hello Tom, Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: My problem was the database connection.  I fixed that and the input controls worked again.  I'm not sure if your problem is related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time I found the solution,solution is very simple just remove the **repo**  from hyperlink path.

```
 "repo:/path of hyperlinked report"
```

hyperlink will be :-

```
 "/path of hyperlinked report".
```